# Specify Multiple Join Conditions with $lookup in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have these two collections which I want to join as 2 conditions.the examId and the user Id .I am using mongodb version 4 and nodejs.there is no mongoose in my application
exam :

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("5c4c21d8f45b3d53ff8c20a3"),
  "title" : "first azmoon",
  "time" : 600,
  "preLesson" : {
   "label" : "Lesson 13",
   "value" : ObjectId("5c484e1852faa438c36c3da1")
},
}
```

result: 
    `{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c4993d5d0dc6f39c0f324bd"),
    "usrId" : ObjectId("5c484e8852faa438c36c3da2"),
    "lsnId" : ObjectId("5c484e1852faa438c36c3da1"),
    "passedLesson" : false,
    "timePassed" : "",
    "quiz" : {
        "time" : "5",
        "questionTrue" : 0,
        "getScore" : 0,
        "permission" : true,
        "quizScore" : 15,
        "quizCount" : 3
    },
    "exam" : {
        "examScore" : 0,
        "examCount" : 0,
        "getScore" : 0,
        "time" : 600,
        "questionTrue" : 0,
        "permission" : false,
        "exId" : ObjectId("5c4c21d8f45b3d53ff8c20a3")
    }
}`

I want the result which its psodou SQL code is like this:

```
select * from exams left join result on exam._id = result.exam.exaId 
     where result.usrId =  ObjectId("5c484e8852faa438c36c3da2")
```

I have done the following but it only joins exam and result without any condition

```
   con.collection("exam").aggregate([
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "result",
                    let: {exaId: "$_id"},
                    pipeline: [
                        {
                            $match: {
                                $expr: {
                                    $and: [
                                         {$eq: ["exam.exId", "exaId"]},
                                        {"usrId": new 
                                       ObjectID(`${usrId}`)}
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    ],
                    as: "result"
                }
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "lesson",
                    localField: "preLesson.value",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "lesson"
                },

            }
        ])
```

I dont know what is the problem,I will appreciate if anyone could help me please with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed `$` sign inside `$eq` operator

```
con.collection("exam").aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "result",
    "let": { "exaId": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": {
        "$expr": { "$eq": ["$exam.exId", "$$exaId"] },
        "usrId": mongoose.Types.ObjectID(`${usrId}`)
      }}
    ],
    "as": "result"
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "lesson",
    "localField": "preLesson.value",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "lesson"
  }}
])
```